# Reduce no of points in X axis HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart with 4 curves . The X axis has many points , so it appears very congested . I have enabled zooming on X axis , so after zooming , values are fine but on initial rendering , values On X Axis are very close . Is there any way to show less points initially , then on zooming in it shows more values or any other option like adding scrollbar.

below code adds zoom :

```
> chart: {
>             zoomType: 'x'
>         },
```

For complete code please find fiddle below

: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/fjaq8v9m/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1) get rid of categories. The chart will naturally select an appropriate number of ticks to display.  If you are unhappy with what it selects, you can explicitly set the `tickInterval` property.

2) if you want your labels to say 'Week x', you can make that happen with the label formatter function:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fjaq8v9m/2/

3) If your data doesn't start at week 1, you can use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fjaq8v9m/3/

4) alternatively, you can use a `datetime` axis type, and set the label formatting to return as the week number.

Comment: thanks it worked. Is it possible to have single json object for above example , so that I dont need to add 4 different arrays in data: for highchart .. Thanks